# "Aim" vs "Goal" whats the difference?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between "Aim" and "Goal"?
I often seen while filling the Resume or Bio-data, there were two fields as:

> **Aim:**
>   **Goals:**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, *aim, goal, objective* can be considered synonyms, but consider these Google Books results:

> [long-term aim](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22long-term%20aim%22&oq=%22long-term%20aim%22&gs_l=serp.3...3883.6091.4.6352.9.9.0.0.0.0.59.397.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.Nk9RLfm-pnE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 197,000; [short-term aim](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22short-term%20aim%22&oq=%22short-term%20aim%22&gs_l=serp.3...5067.7307.3.7568.7.7.0.0.0.0.110.442.6j1.7.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.9VLbYSVRLq0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 32,500
>    [long-term goal](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22long-term%20goal%22&oq=%22long-term%20goal%22&gs_l=serp.3...10250.14385.1.14815.13.13.0.0.0.0.72.741.13.13.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.RSjMfRWWQq0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 255,000; [short-term goal](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22short-term%20goal%22&oq=%22short-term%20goal%22&gs_l=serp.3...4449.6409.2.6942.9.9.0.0.0.0.96.556.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.yqrhVs8-7ro&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 471,000
>    [long-term objective](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22long-term%20objective%22&oq=%22long-term%20objective%22&gs_l=serp.3...10452.12544.0.13049.9.9.0.0.0.0.140.550.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.iDM1o1rVXms&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 115,000; [short-term objective](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sort-term%20objective%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22short-term%20objective%22&spell=1&sa=X&ei=dkk_Ud2JHs-u7Abg0IHQBA&ved=0CC8QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=887) 161,000

I think what that tells us is that *aims* tend to be more *general, vague, non-specific, long-term*, compared to *goals*, which are more likely to be *specific, short-term* targets (*objectives* are somewhere in between, or more accurately, they simply have no relationship with this distinction).

Thus, you're more likely to have a long-term strategic *aim/objective* which is broken down into component *goals* in pursuit of that *aim*, rather than a *goal* which is achieved by meeting several subsidiary *aims*. But this distinction is nowhere near a "rule", and few would see anything odd in reversing the usages.

In the context of a resume or curriculum vitae, I'd probably use *objective*, if for no other reason than it sounds a bit more formal/professional.

---

EDIT: Regarding the point about ***goals*** being more associated with ***short-term*** aims, I think it's worth pointing out that ***a goal*** in ball/puck game contexts (*soccer*, say) is just one step towards the aim / objective (to win the game). A bit like [*Winning the **battle** not the **war**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22winning%20the%20battle%20not%20the%20war%22)

Comment: `I'd probably use objective` But that has a different meaning. Objectives are **concrete** goals/aims, whereas goals and aims can less specific. Always be careful using 'fancy' English, because words often have a slightly different connotation.

Comment: @sanchises: I'm not aware of that distinction. If there were any truth to the idea that *objectives* are more (or indeed, *less*) "concrete" than *aims* or *goals* I'd expect that to be reflected in Google Ngrams for either **our [overall | specific] [aim | goal | objective]**. But in fact, *objective* sits right between *aim* and *goal*, regardless of whether it's *specific* or *overall*. None of these terms are "fancy" though - it's just that *goal* is a bit more informal, and *objective* is a bit more military/corporate.

Comment: [Here's the chart if you're interested](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+overall+objective%2Cour+overall+goal%2Cour+overall+aim%2Cour+specific+objective%2Cour+specific+goal%2Cour+specific+aim&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20overall%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20overall%20goal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20overall%20aim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20specific%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20specific%20goal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%20specific%20aim%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

From my computer dictionary(WordWeb):

> ### Goal
>
> 1. The state of affairs that a plan is *intended to achieve* and that (when achieved) terminates behaviour intended to achieve it
> 2. The place designated as the end
>
> ### Aim
>
> 1. Move into a desired direction of discourse
> 2. Intend (something) to move **towards** a *certain goal*
> 3. The action of directing something at an object

Comment: But this compares *goal*, a noun, with the verb *aim* rather than the noun *aim*.

Answer (score 0):

**Goal is the target that I want to achieve**

> Example: I wish to become an engineer.

**Aim is determined course I set to achieve my target**

> Example: I plan to get B.E. degree to become an engineer.